# Is it possible to create a view which is an upsampling of a table

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible in postgres to create a view of a table, which has the same columns as the original except the rows are upsampled in time?

Most of the examples I've found so far have to do with averaging/downsampling.

Say for instance I have a table "data" which has columns:

```
+---------------------+---+---+
|        time         | x | y |
+---------------------+---+---+
| 2019-07-17 21:00:00 | 4 | 8 |
| 2019-07-17 21:10:00 | 2 | 5 |
| 2019-07-17 21:20:00 | 1 | 7 |
+---------------------+---+---+
```

Where time is a TIMESTAMP given in 10 minute instances.  For aligning with other tables I'd like to make a view where time is 1 second, and x and y hold there 10 minute value fixed over that interval.  Generating a new table with 600x more rows:

```
+---------------------+---+---+
|        time         | x | y |
+---------------------+---+---+
| 2019-07-17 21:00:00 | 4 | 8 |
| 2019-07-17 21:00:01 | 4 | 8 |
| 2019-07-17 21:00:02 | 4 | 8 |
...
| 2019-07-17 21:10:00 | 2 | 5 |
+---------------------+---+---+
```

Comment: I've added input and output tables, will this work?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=fa32c651acc56cac7bc3804ff9406f7b)

```
CREATE VIEW v_data AS

SELECT
    gs,
    x, y
FROM (
    SELECT 
        mytime, 
        lead(mytime) OVER (ORDER BY mytime) AS next_time, -- 1
        x, y
    FROM data
) s,
generate_series(                                          -- 2
    mytime, 
    COALESCE(next_time - interval '1 second', mytime),    -- 3
    interval '1 second'
) AS gs
```

1. The [`lead()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) allows to get the next time value into the current row
2. With the current and the next time value you are able to generate a time series using the function of `generate_series()` (in the fiddle minute steps are taken instead of seconds for more readability). The begin and the end are both timestamps. The generated series are (lateral) joined to each "start" timestamp.
3. If you have a closer look into the second step in the fiddle, you might see that there are two records for `21:10:00` and the last `x`/`y` pair is missing. That is because the series generation always adds the bounds. So for `21:00` to `21:10` it takes the upper bound, which is `21:10`. For the next interval from `21:10` to `21:20` it takes the same value as lower bound. This is why the upper bound should be the step before: It is subtracted. The very last step is difficult too. The `lead()` window function finds no next record, because it is the last one. So the `next_time` value is `NULL`. But `NULL` is not a valid parameter for calculating some series. To get the very last record, the `COALESCE()` function is taken, which takes the first parameter as upper bound as well when real upper bound is `NULL`.